# Links not working on wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress

I have added some html to a wordpress homepage I am working on.

It is a ul of images, simple.

The links [within the services image gallery] are not working, I set them in the usual way.

Some don’t have links but most do, this is confusing.

http://zma.uk.com/zmademo/

Comment: Do you mean the links inside the div "services" are not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1 :** 
If you are asking about that booking Icon,You haven't anchor tag inside `<li>`.Please check if you have custom theme and you are put direct `<li>`.

**Case 2:**
**First Take backup of DB.**

Please Login to wordpress admin and update  your urls,

`Settings->Paramlinks->Custom`

Save changes.

Comment: Thank you @jelly46,I think you are beginner in wp.Please refer a wordpress codex.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.

What I just found that seems to work for me:

1. Edit link while editing the post
2. Click the link settings icon
3. Click on the "Open in new tab" checkbox
4. Click the Update button in the modal "Insert/edit link" dialog box
5. Click the Update button in the Publish box to the right
6. Hover over the home icon to see a drop down menu
7. Choose "Visit Site" and see the links on the homepage

I can't explain why, but that seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It turned out to be an error on the server. Here is how I solved it. You will need root privileges:

1. I used a text editor to open the file apache2.conf

   ```
    gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
   ```

under FollowSymLinks and /var/www/ change

```
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
```

to

```
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
```

For example:

Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted

```
    <Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    #<Directory /srv/>
    #   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    #   AllowOverride None
    #   Require all granted
    #</Directory>
```

2. After updating this, you will need to restart your server. For example:

   ```
    systemctl restart apache2
   ```

or

```
    sudo service apache2 restart
```